# Empty texts are being sent periodically to specific contact?

Tags: sms

When I check my text messages, I am always a bit confused this week. A specific contact in my phone is being sent blank messages over and over again, and I cannot figure out why. What is even more interesting is that the contact that this is happening to does not receive these messages at all. I switched texting apps from Google Messenger to Hangouts hoping the app was just glitching, but still the blank messages continue to appear. They come in groups, one being sent every 2 hours or so (but not in a predicable manner) in packs of 5 to 8 or 9.

I've narrowed down every cause I can think of. All I am down to is my Pebble Time Steel smartwatch or the Android operating system itself that could be causing this.

Anyone have any suggestions to figuring out why this is happening? I don't believe it's the Pebble or the contact in question would be receiving a lot of blank messages and none of these messages appear to go through.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I also have Avast Anti-theft set up, and for some reason all of the messages I send or receive are being forwarded to this contact via binary which is why the messages are empty and why the contact's iPhone is ignoring them.

In short, a bug with avast is the cause. Going to have to give their support a piece of my mind for driving me crazy for two weeks.